# TypeScript: inheritance + recursion

Tags: typescript, inheritance

Please look at the example below.

```
class A {
    public nodes: A;
    constructor(data, instance: new (data) => any) {
        this.nodes = data.children.map(child => new instance(child));
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public nodes: B;
    constructor(data) {
        super(data,B);
    }
}

class C extends A {
    public nodes: C;
    constructor(data) {
        super(data,C);
    }
}
```

I want to create nodes in all classes inherited from class A, defining the creation of these nodes in class A. Now I did this as written above. I want to know if there is a nicer way to do this?

Comment: Provide typing for `data` and `instance` variables and it would be good.

Comment: @zerkms Unfortunately, I cannot set the type for the `instance`, because it can be any inherited class from class A (same for `data`, cause it depends from the class)

Comment: Does your code even work? Because just by reading it, I am not sure it does. If you call `new B(data)` that calls the super constructor and the super constructor invokes `new B` again (as `new instance`). Which should logically call the super constructor and go into an infinite recursion. Or maybe just throw an error. I suppose it depends on what shape `data` has. And I'm still not sure why you're not using generics here. This doesn't feel like an **is-a** relationship between `A`, `B`, and `C`. You might need composition to solve your design problem first.

Comment: @VLAZ regarding infinite recursion: `new instance` is called only for child nodes (thus, it is called as long as each subsequent node has child nodes).
about why I do not use generic: the entry like `new B <B> (data)` or `new C<C>(data)` looks strange to me. But at the same time I would still like to know which of the solutions is the best...

Answer (score 1):

> About why I do not use generic: the entry like `new B<B>(data)` or new `C<C>(data)` looks strange to me.

You need to use generics in order to do this, but `B` and `C` don't need to be generic.  They can extend specific types of the generic base `A`.  So you'll just call `new B(data)`.

We can derive some of the required types just from looking at the usage.

```
this.nodes = data.children.map(child => new instance(child));
```

This line here tells me that the `data` variable which is passed to the constructor has a `children` property.  `children` is an array where every element is assignable to the same type as `data`.

`children` seems to be required here, in which case terminal nodes would have `{children: []}`.  That's fine if that's what you want, but typically it is optional such that terminal nodes do not have a `children` property at all.

```
type Recursive<OwnData> = OwnData & {
    children?: Array<Recursive<OwnData>>;
}
```

So we get this type `Recursive<OwnData>`, which is a generic that depends on a variable `OwnData` where `OwnData` represents all properties other than `children`.

We do not know what goes on inside the constructors of individual descendants of `A` and we do not know what unique instance variables they might declare.  So for maximum flexibility, we should assume that the properties of `data` and the properties of a node aren't always the same.  This means that `A` needs two generics.

```
class A<DataProps, NodeType> {
    public nodes: Array<NodeType>;

    constructor(
        data: Recursive<DataProps>,
        instance: new (data: Recursive<DataProps>) => NodeType
    ) {
        this.nodes = data.children ? data.children.map(child => new instance(child)) : [];
    }
}
```

Now when we create a subclass, we extend a specific version of `A<DataProps, NodeType>`.  We can pass the subclass itself as the type for `NodeType`.

```
type BData = {
    b: number;
}

class B extends A<BData, B> {
    public b: number;

    constructor(data: Recursive<BData>) {
        super(data, B);
        this.b = data.b;
    }

    someFunc(): void {
        console.log(this.b);
    }
}

const bInst = new B({b: 1, children: [{b: 2}, {b: 3}]});
// each node of `bInst` is `B`
bInst.nodes.map(b => b.someFunc() );
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/lWYAdW)